# Can Powershell automate the creation of individual ZIP files for each file in a directory?

Tags: powershell

**Question:**
Can Powershell automatically create an individual zipped archive file for each object that it finds within a directory?

**Background:**

- A directory with a couple of hundred files in it (various file types)
- I need to create a zipped archive for each one of them.

**Concept Workflow:**

1. Powershell Script is pointed to a directory
2. Powershell discovers a bunch of files (various extensions)
3. Powershell automatically compresses "Widget.CFG" into a .ZIP file
4. Process repeats against every other object found within that same directory

**Environment:**

- Windows 7/64 Bit OS
- Powershell version 5 (Major: 5  Minor: 1  Build: 15363  Revision:786)

Is this possible?

The script I have come up with (below) does not produce any outputs, and I'm stumped as to why.

**What I have so far:**

```
$Path = "C:\ziptest"   

function Compress-ChildItem {   
    [CmdletBinding()]   
    param(   
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]   
        [ValidateNotNull()]   
        [System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]]   
        $Path   
    )   
    process {   
        Get-ChildItem -File $Path | ForEach-Object {   
            $NewName = "{0}-{1}.zip" -f $_.BaseName, ($_.Extension -replace '.')   
            $CompressionParams = @{   
                DestinationPath = Join-Path $Path -ChildPath $NewName   
                Path = $_.FullName   
            }   
            Compress-Archive @CompressionParams   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell and Windows would this be used on?

Comment: - Windows 7/64 Bit OS
 - Powershell version 5 (Major: 5  Minor: 1  Build: 15363  Revision:786)

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While @DavidPostill is quite correct in his comment, I will offer you some basic assistance to get started: I commend your attention to [this Hey, Scripting Guy!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/03/09/use-powershell-to-create-zip-archive-of-folder/) and Microsoft's documentation on the [`Compress-Archive`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Edited post as requested.  Please remove the hold?

Comment: is the `Compress-Archive @CompressionParams` a typo?  Because it should be `$CompressionParams`